# Inconsistent Symbol Mangling in Rust on Windows

Tags: windows, rust

I have two interdependent, cross platform Rust projects. Project A is the main application, producing the main executable and a dynamic library containing common dependencies. Project B contains plugins for the application, each distributed as a dynamic library with a dependency on the Project A common library.

Because the two projects are separate, Cargo builds the common library with both projects A and B. On Windows, symbol name mangling is inconsistent between the two builds, meaning that the Project B plugins cannot use the common library produced from the Project A build, and vice versa. I also tried placing a `#[no_mangle]` directive on the pertinent symbols in the Project A common library, but on Windows it is ignored in the Project B build.

On Linux, the symbol names are consistent between the two builds, with or without the `#[no_mangle]` directive.

What could be causing this inconsistency on Windows builds and how can it be resolved? I would like to keep the two projects separate to make it easier to develop new plugins in the future.

All testing has been done using Rust 1.13.0 on Windows 10 and CentOS 7. This issue occurs with both the MSVC and GNU ABIs on Windows, but the application ultimately needs to compile with the MSVC ABI.

Comment: Please produce a [MCVE] (emphasis on the **minimal**). As it is right now, I don't understand your project setup, so I cannot reproduce it in a VM. I will note that the Rust ABI *is not stable*, so any dynamic libraries **must** use the C ABI if you hope for them to actually be compatible, at least across Rust versions.